# How to remove a merged branch that is deep in the history?

Tags: git

I have a testing branch that has a feature branch merged into it some 8 months ago.  It's clear this feature branch isn't going to go anywhere so I'd like to remove it. 
 I can't do things like revert because there are too many parents.  Everything I've hit upon so far is about fixing something in the recent history.  This is buried in the history of this branch.  Any ideas?

Comment: Everything that is overwritten removes the history of the branch

Comment: I'm not necessarily asking to overwrite the branch or to remove history.  If I can show that things were reversed and keep history, that's fine with me.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with git revert, can you explain what you tried and what the problem was? `git revert SHA -m 2` or `git revert SHA -m 1` *should* be what you need.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen make that an answer?